# Careers translation

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, localization

*Founded* is translated to *Trouvé* instead of *Fondé*.

It's amusing, *Trouver* is *to find*.

Ideally that would be "**Fondée en xxxx**"

Example page: https://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/conix

Comment: Perhaps the English should be "Found" instead? ;)

Comment: Someone hole the ground a found a company, it's look like petrol.

Comment: I think in two hours time there will be a complaint letter sent to Google translate... (*Kidding BTW*)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed! Or, should I say: réparé?

Comment: "Corrigé" , when it's about typo!

Comment: Ah, got it. Merci!